# Extract peaks from a signal

Tags: c#, matlab, signal-processing

I have a signal which is depicted in the following image:

[image]

I want to calculate the 4 high peaks that occur inside the signal. Is there any algorithm that can detect my signal?

Comment: You'll probably get better help at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What calculation do you want? Just the local maxima of already recorded data, then use [`findpeaks`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) in Matlab. If this is not what you are looking for, please edit your question to include more information about what you would like to achieve.

Comment: THe problem with findpeaks that it calculate all local maxima all the peaks. I want just to find the four main peaks. Moreover except from the peak I want to find the length of the peak.

Comment: So why can't you pick the top four peaks with the highest amplitude and the length of the peaks by looking at the two closest minimas...?

Comment: I want to detect the whole curve, not just the max value. Curves correspond to an event. Continuously big values is not correspond to desired events.

Comment: This figure is an example. I dont know  a priori how many peaks I have in my signal. Thus I want to find how many complete curves 9from zero to one and back to zero there approximately) are in my signal.

Comment: What do you mean by 'whole curve'? Define curve. And 'from zero to one'... there are no axis labels in your image. Also give more image examples of which peaks you want and which should be ignored.

Comment: Yes you are right. Y-axis takes values from 0-1. THe whole curve I mean a peak from 0-1 and back to 0. Likewise the QRS in the ECG signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this?

```
[localmax,maxind] = findpeaks(x);
inversex = 1.01*max(x) - x;
[localmin,minind] = findpeaks(inversex);
%//this gives all maxima and minima, now you can compute the width.

%//as for the top 4 peaks, surely you just sort and index 1:4 upon the result or in the beginning.
```

Comment: Why am I need the first line in your proposed code?

Comment: knowing the local minima allows you to compute the width of each local maxima; since you want to maxima with highest values (top 4), the first line is the actual answer, where as the second and third line helps you to define the width